# Programa que da de alta a un usuario en java, me gustaría saber sus recomendaciones para poder mejorarlo

Tags: java, revisión-de-código

```
*fecha:16/04/17

*"programa encargado de solicitar 
* alta de usuario con parametros 
*especificos el numero celular y password, 
posteriormente le solicita que 
confirme la contraseña*/

public class checking_password
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        revision_password autentificacion=new revision_password();
    }
}

class revision_password {

    private String number_Phone="";
    private final static String MATCH_NUMBER_PHONE="[0-9]{10}";
    private String password="";
    private final static String MATCH_PASSWORD="[0-9a-zA-Z]{10}";
    private Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

    public revision_password(){

        Welcome_Mensage();
        rev_password();
    }
    /*metodo con mensaje de bienvenida
    * e invitacion a ingresar datos*/
    private void Welcome_Mensage(){

        System.out.println("Hola!, gracias por elegir \"FUTURE TECH\" \n");
        System.out.println("para poder disfrutar de nuestro servicio\nnecesitas darte de alta con tu numero\ncelular y contraseña\n");
        System.out.println("Introduce tu numero celular de 10 degitos");
        }

    /* metodo encargado de almacenar
    *los datos de usuario*/
     private void rev_password(){
         boolean band_Password_Number=true;
         boolean band_Password_Contra=true;
         String Cofirmacion_Password="";

     while(band_Password_Number){
             number_Phone=entrada.next();
    if(number_Phone.matches(MATCH_NUMBER_PHONE)){
       System.out.println("correcto");

            band_Password_Number=false;
        }

    if(!number_Phone.matches(MATCH_NUMBER_PHONE)){
       System.out.println("numero ingresado incorrecto,\n ingreselo de nuevo");

        }
    }

    while(band_Password_Contra){
        System.out.println("introduce tu contraseña, que deben ser 10 caracteres\n y pueden ser\"numeros y letras MAY/MIN\"");

        password=entrada.next();

        if(password.matches(MATCH_PASSWORD)){
            System.out.println("porfavor confirmela de nuevo");

                Cofirmacion_Password=entrada.next();
                if(password.equalsIgnoreCase(Cofirmacion_Password)){

                    System.out.println("es correcto");
                    band_Password_Contra=false;

                }
                if(!password.equalsIgnoreCase(Cofirmacion_Password)){
                    System.out.println("error porfavor buelva a introducir su contraseña");
                    band_Password_Contra=true;
                }
            }

            if(!password.matches(MATCH_PASSWORD)){
                System.out.println("datos incorectos favor de ingresarlos de nuevo");

                band_Password_Contra=true;
            }

          System.out.println("usuario registrado");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Para empezar, un primer paso sería aplicar bien la convención de nombres, como se explica aquí: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367  Si esto es una constante: `MATCH_PASSWORD` está bien aplicada en ese caso. Pero aquí no: `band_Password_Contra`, sea lo que sea, pues esa convención de nombres no se recomienda. No es motivo de error, pero es parte de mejorar el código. Por otro lado, tu pregunta es muy general, si no indicas datos más precisos como en qué tienes dudas de que el código no esté optimizado, es difícil darte una respuesta.

Comment: Lo que me comentas es lo que estaba buscando, ya que quiero mejorar mi código y quiero que sea lo más legible posible, te agradezco mucho tus recomendaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El sistema no deja todavía hacer comentarios, por lo que te lo pongo por aqui:

En primer lugar como bien dijo Eduardo lo primero de todo sería usar la convención de nombres de constantes en mayúsculas y nombres de métodos con Camel Case

Yo separaría el main en otra clase pero eso ya es una manía mía

Sería conveniente darle una pista al usuario de los requerimientos de la contraseña con un mensaje por ejemplo:
Solo se aceptan letras minúsculas, mayúsculas y números con una longitud máxima de diez carácteres

Tambien revisaría la ortografía en las líneas:

47:

String Cofirmacion_Password;

79:

System.out.println("error porfavor buelva a introducir su contraseña");

Algunas tildes no importantes

Tambien he visto que das por hecho que un telefono es de 10 carácteres cuando en realidad es de 9 u once en el caso de que quieras registrar los dos numeros del principio que identifican cada país (en el caso de españa 34)

Si quieres hacer mas legible tu codigo usa el mismo idioma para las variables en todo el código y nombres mas específicos como por ejemplo

band_Password_Number --> phoneNumberOK

Cofirmacion_Password --> passwordOK

Añadiría un asterisco a tus comentarios para documentar los métodos nose en que IDE trabajas pero en netbeans necesitas empezar por /** para que te lo pille como javadoc quedaría asi el método rev_password()

```
/**
 * metodo encargado de almacenar los datos de usuario
 */
```

Por último yo usaría LOGs para registrar entradas a métodos por si ocurre alguna excepción saber por donde ha pasado no debería saltar excepción pero, quien sabe...

A bote pronto esto es lo que vi mirando tu código puede que me deje alguna cosa

Un saludo y gracias por leerme

Comment: Gracias por tus recomendaciones. No se me podrías explicar como funcionan  los Los o la documentación en donde pueda leer información

Comment: Lo de los LOG va por clases lo único que tendrás que hacer es añadir al principio de la clase: private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(NombreClase.class.getName()); y luego usar LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "mensaje {0}", ex.getMessage()); entre otros muchos que hay cambiando el WARNING porel que mas te convenga el {0} es para reemplazarlo por los parametros a partir del 2º para contatenar Strings

Comment: Ok gracias por tu aporte

Comment: nada, para eso estamos ;)